# Invalid object name in SSMS for table in SQL Server 2016

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2016

I created a table using an EF Core 2.1 migration and was able to populate it using EF in C#.  The table shows in SSMS Object Explorer and I can execute queries against the table using "Edit top 200 rows" and "Select top 1000 rows".  I tried an ad-hoc query:

```
use ArielOpnsDB
go

select * from ZipCodeCities
```

The table, ZipCodeCities, is show with the error, "Invalid object name 'ZipCodeCities'.  Queries against all other tables and it shows in the creation scripts generated in SSMS.

What could be the problem and how can it be fixed?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe it is not in the dbo schema? To check this, try to find your table in the SQL Server metadata table with 
`select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_NAME ='ZipCodeCities'`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I checked and the table is in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES. The problem lies elsewhere.